# How to install Openface in windows python

Tags: python, windows, installation, deep-learning, face-recognition

I am a newbie to Openface. Due to some reasons I want to install Openface in windows with python. It would be great if anyone could guide me through that. I have searched online, but not a single article talks about windows python installation. May be I am asking a very simple question but please help me through this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of OpenFace being used on Windows directly, but please contribute any changes necessary to the repository if you start working on this. I expect there to be a few compatibility issues with Linux-only features.

A workaround solution is to the prebuilt OpenFace Docker container on Windows with a Docker machine. Some of this is from the [OpenFace setup guide](http://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/setup/#with-docker). First [start a Linux Docker machine on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/). Then pull the OpenFace docker container from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/bamos/openface/):

```
docker pull bamos/openface
docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash
cd /root/openface
./demos/compare.py images/examples/{lennon*,clapton*}
./demos/classifier.py infer models/openface/celeb-classifier.nn4.small2.v1.pkl ./images/examples/carell.jpg
./demos/web/start-servers.sh
```

Comment: I think this is the only way. Can't Install on windows, have to use docker only.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to install openface in windows which worked for me.

1. Download openface from this path- http://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/
2. Paste the folder openface into the path where python.exe file exist.
3. Run the commnd python openface/setup.py install

Comment: Don't believe this works. Did you actually run an openface application and see it work?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **anaconda**, then the following steps worked for me. The credit for the steps goes to nitish11 who posted them in github: https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/82d0ea0fdb56dc93cb9b716e7ceb364b

1. Open the command line from within anaconda.
2. If required, install git (`conda install -c anaconda git`)
3. `git clone https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface.git`
4. `cd openface`
5. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
6. `(sudo) python setup.py install`

`sudo` may not be required in step 6.

Hope this helps.